# Implementing multiple network calls in iOS programmatically in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am an iOS application developer. I am implementing NSURLConnection in iOS to handle webservices calls.

In my application I want to implement the multiple network connection simultaneously. And also I want full control over stopping the network call manually.

For example , I am navigating to table view which fills data from server using connection on background thread so in this case the UI is responsive. But lets say I want to navigate back from this tableView in this case the connection is not stopped. I want to stop it.

Please help me with this scenario. I want my UI responsive anyway. Thanks a lot. It will be really helpful.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: If you use the delegate-based rendition of `NSURLConnection`, you can keep a reference to your `NSURLConnection` and call the `cancel` method when you dismiss the view controller.

Comment: One approach to implement concurrent network requests, is to subclass `NSOperation` which encapsulates a `NSULRConnection` or a `NSURLSession`/`NSURLSessionTask` which use a delegate based implementation.

Comment: Thanks Rob and CouchDeveloper for the helpful reply. Currently I am trying out both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NSOperation/NSOperationQueue` to manage the states of your operations, which includes suspending and canceling operations.

[NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-SW6)

[NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/)

Comment: Or just use AFNetworking, which wraps `NSURLConnection` in `NSOperation`s for your. Plus a bunch of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

use a property to store the NSURLConnection.  For your ViewController override dealloc, or ViewWillDisapper (depending on your design) call the cancel method on the NSURLConnection

Comment: Thanks Cris. I will try this out for my scenario.